# Ipython3 notebook doesn't run after installed with macports

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, macports

I installed the Python3.4 version of IPython and Ipython notebook with

```
sudo port install py34-ipython
sudo port install py34-notebook
```

Currently I am using Python 3.4.3 as my version of Python3.

If I use `ipython3 notebook`, the web browser pops up. If I try to open up a new notebook however, the kernel immediately shuts down.

```
$ipython3 notebook
[W 18:02:47.712 NotebookApp] ipywidgets package not installed.  Widgets are unavailable.
[I 18:02:47.727 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/MYNAME
[I 18:02:47.727 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 18:02:47.727 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 18:02:47.727 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 18:03:27.826 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[W 18:03:28.518 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20151208180247 (::1) 9.24ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled67.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
[I 18:03:28.693 NotebookApp] Kernel started: bccd5587-5da7-47a3-9c8f-90947b4140eb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 151, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 118, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 104, in _get_module_details
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(mod_name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/importlib/util.py", line 86, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 17, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .manager import KernelManager, run_kernel
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .session import Session
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 48, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import IOLoop
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import IOLoop
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tornado.ioloop import PollIOLoop, PeriodicCallback
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 57, in <module>
    import thread  # py2
  File "/Users/MYNAME/thread.py", line 10
    print old, new
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
[I 18:03:31.692 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `/Users/MYNAME/thread.py` is in Python 2 syntax.
Change to a different directory or remove this file or change the name of this file. Then start the notebook server again. The name `thread.py` shadows that of a standard library module in Python 2. IPython runs with Python 2 and 3 with the same source code and imports the wrong file.

Comment: I'm using Macports to install both versions. Perhaps I should install them in separate directories...

Comment: Did you do the steps in my answer and did they work?

Comment: Well, as I would like to use macports to install both, as I would like to use this package manager to keep all modules updated. I'm not sure at the moment what to do really....Perhaps I should report this as a bug.

Comment: There should be nothing installed in `/Users/MYNAME/thread.py`. Can you `cd` in a different directory and try again. I am just trying to help. Please do as I recommend and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that that doesn't help. Using macports, it looks like the dependencies for the Python2.7 version of ipython notebook clashes with the Python 3.4 version

Comment: Same error message, same behavior, i.e. kernel shuts down immediately

Comment: Please type `cd` and tell me what it says.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97351/discussion-between-mike-muller-and-shanzhengyang).